# Count even and odd intergers until 0 is encountered

Tags: java, loops

Here is what I have to do:

> "Write a segment of code that reads a sequence of integers from the keyboard until the user enters a negative number.  It should then output a count of the number of even integers and the number of odd integers read (not including the final negative value in either count).  Remember - 0 is an even number.  For example, if the sequence is:
>
> ```
> 2
> 7
> 15
> 5
> 88
> 1243
> 104
> -1
> ```
>
> Then the output should be
>
> ```
> Number of even integers: 3
> Number of odd integers: 4
> ```

My code just keeps going even after inputting -1. I have a feeling I am missing a `{`somewhere or wrote the code wrong. Here is my code:

```
int oddCount = 0, evenCount = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (oddCount>=0&&evenCount>=0){
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int temp = in.nextInt();
        if (temp>0) {
            if (temp%2==0)
                evenCount = evenCount + 1;
            else oddCount = oddCount + 1;
            while (temp>0);
        System.out.println("Number of even integers: "+evenCount);
        System.out.println("Number of odd integers: " +oddCount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Terminating condition on your title, and your question don't match.

Comment: Hint: where are you _checking_ for -1 (or 0, or whatever), and what are you doing to exit the loop when you see it?

Comment: oddCount>=0&&evenCount>=0 is always true

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

First, since you never decrease `oddCount` and `evenCount`, the condition `oddCount>=0&&evenCount>=0` will always be `true`.

Second, you have an empty loop that loops endlessly, since it's condition is `true` and it has no body: `while (temp>0);`

I'd just take out the first loop, which is redundant, and use a `do while` loop:

```
int oddCount = 0;
int evenCount = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int temp = in.nextInt();
    if (temp > 0) {
        if (temp % 2==0) {
            evenCount++;
        } else {
            oddCount++;
        }
     }
 } while (temp > 0);

 System.out.println("Number of even integers: " + evenCount);
 System.out.println("Number of odd integers: "  + oddCount);
```

Comment: It says it's missing a while (expression) to complete do

Comment: @user3290019 I was missing a '}' - fixed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will always continue because `while (oddCount>=0&&evenCount>=0)` will always be true in your case. Try it like this:

```
int oddCount = 0, evenCount = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean continue = true;
while (continue){
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int temp = in.nextInt();
        if (temp>0) {
            if (temp%2==0)
                evenCount++;
            else 
                oddCount++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Number of even integers: "+evenCount);
            System.out.println("Number of odd integers: " +oddCount);
            continue = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using do While loop will also prevent your isses,

```
int oddCount = 0;
int evenCount = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int temp = in.nextInt();
    if (temp > 0) {
        (temp % 2==0)? evenCount++:oddCount++;
    }
 } while (temp > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads just one integer, then stuck at this line: `while (temp>0);`

The code below solve your problem:

```
int oddCount = 0, evenCount = 0, temp;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
while (true) {
    temp = in.nextInt();
    if (temp < 0) {
        break;
    } else if (temp % 2 == 0) {
        evenCount = evenCount + 1;
    } else {
        oddCount = oddCount + 1;
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of even integers: " + evenCount);
System.out.println("Number of odd integers: " + oddCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int evenCount=0, oddCount=0;
while(true)
{
System.out.println("Enter a number");
int n=s.nextInt();
   if(n<0) break;
   if(n%2==0) evenCount+=n;
   else oddCount+=n;
}
System.out.println("even count "+evenCount);
System.out.println("odd count "+oddCount);
```